# Difference b/w the value in html matoption and ts reactive form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

Not understanding where the data is coming from the html or the typescript when you bind data in the typescript AND use an array.

I have gone through the Angular documentation and several tutorials but I am not understanding a few distinctions.

In the HTML for a material form in Angular reactive forms, there is the ngFor and the [value] and the string interpolated item.

In the ngFor, I believe I am pulling from an array created DIRECTLY in TypeScript.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="input-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="Language" formControlName="language" required>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.value">
            {{ language.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
public languages = [
        { value: 'English', viewValue: 'English' },
        { value: 'Spanish', viewValue: 'Spanish' }
    ];
```

However, in the code in TypeScript that creates the form, its pointed to an object that comes from a Database

```
interface AUser{
    Gender: string;
}

public user: AUser;

this.GetUser(id).subscribe(resp => {
    this.user = resp;
};

this._profileForm = this.fb.group({
     'language': [this.user.Language]
});

onClick() {
let userinfo = AUser {
Language: this._pForm.get('language').value
};

this.UpdateUser(userinfo);
```

So where is the data really coming from? The HTML or the TS? 
aka the:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender.value">
```

or the:

```
'language': [this.user.Language]
```

Comment: The data is never coming from the template. The template is only rendering data that is passed to it from the component. In your example, the `*ngFor` is looping through a variable `genders` that must be defined as a class member (in the component). *unless*, the variable is created using a template variable. *see* https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

Comment: Why does the HTML use a variable thats created directly in the TypeScript, but there is a completely different one that comes from the database.. and the page still knows the proper value to show from the database even though I am creating one from scratch in the TS?  ("languages" vs the formgroup "this._profileForm" )?